# List US supermarkets as defined by the Blue Cash Everyday

Tags: data-request, usa, finance

I am looking for a list of shops regarded as US supermarkets for the Blue Cash [Everyday](https://www304.americanexpress.com/credit-card/blue-cash-everyday)/[Preferred](https://www304.americanexpress.com/credit-card/blue-cash-preferred/) Cards from American Express.

The [Benefit Terms](https://www304.americanexpress.com/personal-card-application/terms/blue-cash-everyday-credit-card/28000-10-0/?print#CardBenefitsTerms) point to https://www.americanexpress.com/us/content/rewards-info/retail.html, which gives a vague definition of a US Supermaket along with a quite partial list of US supermarkets.

> U.S. Supermarkets
>
> To earn additional rewards on supermarket purchases,
>   the supermarket must be located in the U.S.
>
> A supermarket offers a wide variety of food and household products
>   such as meat, fresh produce, dairy, canned and packaged goods,
>   household cleaners, pharmacy products and pet supplies.
>
> (Superstores, convenience stores and warehouse clubs are NOT
>   considered supermarkets.)
>
> Examples of merchants* that accept the Card and where you can earn
>   additional rewards include:
>
> - Gristedes
> - Foodtown
> - Pathmark
> - Shoprite
> - Stop and Shop
> - Vons
> - Whole Foods
> - Winn-Dixie
> - Online supermarkets such as FreshDirect
>
> *This is not a complete list.
>
> Examples of merchants where you will NOT earn additional rewards
>   include:
>
> - Specialty stores (e.g., fish markets, cheese shops, wine
>     shops, and other specialty food stores )
> - Superstores (e.g. Amazon,
>     Target and Wal-Mart)
> - Warehouse clubs (e.g. BJ's Club and Costco
>     Wholesale)

I did try calling Amex (800-243-3888). They told me they don't have any list, and that I should instead ask each shop whether they accept AmEx and are regarded as US supermarket. I am hoping that some AmEx customers may have aggregated some list.

Comment: Not the answer you are seeking "Blue Cash Everyday" list, but [Food Atlas Access by USDA ERS](http://www.ers.usda.gov/data-products/food-access-research-atlas.aspx)  has 
[Food Access Research Atlas, and Archived Food Desert Locator](http://www.ers.usda.gov/data-products/food-access-research-atlas/download-the-data.aspx) which may be of use